# Primefaces contextmenu refresh when click on row of treetable

Tags: primefaces, refresh, contextmenu, treetable

the situation is the following: I've got a treeTable with 3 different type of objects. The table contains the p:ajax with event="select". I wrote 3 different contextMenus, one for each type... and all works well.

My problem is that I want to enable/disable some of the menuItems; to do that I use the attribute "rendered" with condition based on properties of selected node.
All works, but only the second time I right-click on the same object (the first time the contextMenu isn't filtered).

Here is the code... (I'm including only one type of object for semplicity)

treeTable page:

```
<h:form id="form" prependId="false">
    <p:treeTable value="#{documentsController.root}" var="document" id="docs" 
            selectionMode="single" selection="#{documentsController.selectedNode}">

        <p:ajax event="select" process="@this" update=":form:menus"/>

        <p:column headerText="#{msg['name']}">
            <h:outputText value="#{document.name}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:treeTable>

    <h:panelGroup id="menus">
        <ui:include src="/menu/document_menu.xhtml"/>
    </h:panelGroup>

    <p:dialog id="document-rename-dialog" widgetVar="documentRenameDialog" header="#{msg.rename}">
        <h:panelGrid id="doc-rename" columns="2">
            <h:outputLabel for="name" value="#{msg.name}:" />
            <h:inputText id="name" value="#{documentsController.name}"/>
        </h:panelGrid>

        <div class="spacer-10" />

        <h:panelGroup layout="block">
            <p:commandLink onclick="documentRenameDialog.hide();" value="#{msg.cancel}"/>
            <p:commandLink actionListener="#{documentsController.renameDocument(documentsController.selectedNode.data)}"
            process="@this :form:document-rename-dialog:doc-rename"
            update=":form:docs"
            oncomplete="documentRenameDialog.hide();"
            value="#{msg.check}">
        </h:panelGroup>
    </common:dialog>
</h:form>
```

document_menu page:

```
<p:contextMenu id="contextMenuDocument" for="docs" nodeType="document">
    <p:menuitem value="#{msg.rename}" process="@this docs" update=":form:document-rename-dialog:doc-rename"
        actionListener="#{documentsController.setName(documentsController.selectedNode.data.name)}"
        rendered="#{documentsController.canWrite}"
        icon="ui-icon-pencil" oncomplete="documentRenameDialog.show();"/>
</p:contextMenu>
```

DocumentsController class:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class DocumentsController {
    private TreeNode root;
    private TreeNode selectedNode;
    private String name;

    public TreeNode getSelectedNode() {
        return selectedNode;
    }

    public void setSelectedNode(TreeNode selectedNode) {
        this.selectedNode = selectedNode;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void renameDocument(ArterDocument selectedDocument) {
        if(name != null && !name.equals("")) {
            System.out.println("Document renamed in: "+name);
            ((MyDocument)selectedNode.getData()).setName(name);
        }
        else
            addErrorMessage("Error renaming document.");
    }

    public static boolean canWrite() {
        if(((MyDocument)selectedNode.getData()).isWriteable())
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

The MyDocument class is a simple class with a String (name) and a boolean (writeable).

Can anyone tell me how I can show filtered contextMenu at first shot?

Thank you!

Comment: I took loadContents function from p:overlayPanel's js and added it to p:contextMenu's js (adapting it and show function to the situation...)
It works, now when I right-click on any of the entry I see the updated contextual menu...

Some things are still missing: a dynamic attribute to indicate (from outside the js) that is needed a reload of content and a process attribute on the p:contextMenu, to process values - eg. selected node in data/tree table - needed to evaluate rendered attributes in p:menuItem.